# Suggested edits for questions which should be closed

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I guess this question was already ask, but neither the site-search nor google brought me any information.

I recently got the required rights to review suggested edits (hooray, more power! ;). A few edits I reviewed left me wondering what I should do with edits to questions which should obviously be closed. Should I still accept them or should I simply skip them? Or should I reject them and if so, should I give any comment (if it applies: Which comment?)?

Comment: How about accept the edits if they are appropriate and then flag them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Annoying answer: it depends.

Somewhat more specific answer: it depends if the question could *ever* be salvaged and if this edit moves it in that direction.

## Editing spam, completely off-topic questions, etc.

If the question clearly shouldn't be here then there isn't much point editing it: we don't want people making perfectly grammatically correct spam. Equally if it's just nothing to do with the site, such as "How do I learn sowing" on Stack Overflow then that is never going to be on topic. Reject in all these cases.

## Editing close-worthy but potentially salvageable questions

The "[on hold]" process is in place rather than an insta-delete process because some questions can be saved; e.g. questions which are unclear or too broad can be made clearer and narrower. If the edit *substantially* improves the post then accept: this leaves the OP with less to do to bring the question on topic. Use your judgement here, consider what is the best overall result.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great answer which actually helps me very much in my decision process. I was talking about the first type of questions you mentioned, so I will reject them from now on.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a *good* edit, it should be accepted.

Why?

In case the question is **not (yet) closed**:

- Maybe your impression is wrong and the question won’t get closed.
- Maybe the edit is a first step for saving the question.

In case the question is **closed**:

- Some closed questions stay on the site. You’ll find (even several years old) closed questions when searching, browsing tags, reading comments etc.
- Maybe the edit is a first step for salvaging the question.

I think it’s especially important to get the tags right. **Retagging** (not-yet-closed | closed) questions makes sure that the relevant experts see them, and that these questions won’t show up on (possibly totally) wrong places on the site.

So, if you review a suggested edit to a question, don’t put on your *close hat* on top of your *review hat*. Approve the edit if it’s a good edit, then switch hats and vote for close.